# Schedule a daily event on a program that runs all day

Tags: c#, events, timer, scheduled-tasks

I am coding a C# WinForms program that I want to have running in the background 24/7. In an XML file, I'm pulling a time. For example: 3:30:00 PM. When I then display this time after parsing it, it comes out as 1/15/2014 3:30:00 PM.

What my question is, based on this XML value, how can I have it so that, at 3:30:00 PM every day, a Timer object or something displays a message box or some other action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using a `Timer` is good. You could use either the `Winforms` `Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`. In this case, I will refer to `System.Timers.Timer` as I have some code I can base this answer off of.

Anyway, just assign it an `Interval` and give an event to fire via `Elapsed`. Then in the code that `Elapsed` calls, put in your action code. Finally, start the timer wherever you need it and try running it.

If you are using a `DateTime` to hold the file data, then you will need to either create a constant number of milliseconds until the next day (not recommended), or do some math using `TimeSpan`s (hint: use the constructor to get the time). The `TimeSpan` contains a property called 'TotalMilliseconds' that you can use as the `Interval`.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

That is a console application that executes a job at a fixed time every day

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
            // Wait for the user to hit <Enter>
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + DateTime.Now);
            DateTime s = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(23, 27, 0);
            s = s.Date + ts;
            if (DateTime.Now > s && !fired) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Do the Job");
                fired = true;
            }
            else if (DateTime.Now < s)
            {
                fired = false;
            }
        }
        private static bool fired = false;
    }
}
```